# IOS App Code Signing Issue - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios-provisioning

We have been developing a large IOS project for the past year - due to the size of the project a new company has been setup to support it - so we have setup a new IOS Developer Licence under the new company name - all pretty straightforward we thought - but its been a real headache trying to switch the configuration over to the new account!

We tried to create the various certificates and provisioning profiles require for the new developer account - after some difficulty - (which eventually involved deleting all profiles and certificates from all devices and starting from scratch) - we managed to get the app to build and provision for an iPhone.  All now resolved - or so we thought.  When testing on the office iPad we discovered we still get the same issue - we basically get the following error message -

```
Check dependencies

Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning     profiles include the device (DEVICE NAME).

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'
```

The Ipad shows up in the provisioning profile in our dev account - but wont provision from xcode.

Tried deleting all certificates and re-installing - but no luck - amazingly frustrating - no idea what to try next - can anyone offer any suggestions!?

Comment: I would download the provisioning profile from the Apple Developer Portal and open it with vim to look whether the UDID of the device is in there. Then I would check whether the build configuration is correct. Then I would delete the Derived Data. Then I would restart the Mac and the iDevice. Then I would clean and try to install. Then I would try to find the provisioning profile which is used by Xcode (it's a bit difficult with Xcode 5) and look into it with vim. Then I would try to use a different Mac. Then I would try to create an ipa and install it using Xcode Organizer.

Comment: cheers for the advice @dasdom I will give all those a go in the morning and see if they work.  Frustrating these certificates/ profiles heh!  Cheers

Comment: It really is. I wonder how much money has been wasted during the fight developer vs insanely bad certificate voodoo.

Comment: Hi @dasdom - I followed your advice - downloaded the provisioning profile (didnt contain correct id) - cleared derived data - restarted - clicked fix and all worked!  cheers for that - add as an answer and I'll give you a tick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

1. Download the provisioning profile from the Apple Developer Portal and open it with vim to look whether the UDID of the device is in there.
2. Check whether the build configuration is correct.
3. Delete the Derived Data.
4. Restart the Mac and the iDevice.
5. Clean and try to install.
6. Try to find the provisioning profile which is used by
   Xcode (it's a bit difficult with Xcode 5) and look into it with vim.
7. Try to use a different Mac.
8. Try to create an ipa and install it using Xcode
   Organizer.